# Iterate through elements, adding click event to each of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, each

jQuery newbie here.

If I have this html:

```
<ul id="floor-selector">
    <li id="floor-1">Ground Floor</li>
    <li id="floor-2">Second Floor</li>
    <li id="floor-3">Third Floor</li>
    <li id="floor-4">Premier Floor (Premier Floor)</li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a `click` event to each `li` item, such that I can get the `id` of the element I am on. Right now I just have an alert with the index I'm on (and it's not working either), but I really want the ID of the item I'm on, not the index of the array returned by my selector.

Here's what I tried, but it doesn't seem to work, I think I might have the wrong understanding of `each()` or `click()`.

```
$('#floor-selector li').each( function(index, node) {
    node.click( function(){ alert('I am on the '+index+'th element'); } );
    // but I really want to get the ID of this element
  });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#floor-selector li').on('click', function() {
    alert('I am the '+$(this).attr('id')+' element');
});
```

Behind the scenes jQuery does a bunch of magic and essentially binds the function you pass to the element. `this` therefore references the element that you are clicking and passing it to jQuery functio: `$(this)` gives you back that element wrapped in a jQuery object. Of course you could simply access the `id` on `this` directly.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch! So, do all jquery functions iterate across arrays like 'on' does here?

Comment: AFAIK when you have a jQuery object, calling a function on it will apply to all matched elements. E.g. calling a function on `$('div')` would call it on each div in the DOM.